# Utilizar la función SUM() en un Group by

Tags: c#

Cordial saludo. En la actualidad estamos buscando obtener la suma dentro de un group by. realizamos este código pensando que funcionaria bien, pero no fue así, este el código:

```
protected void CVSumaUbicaciones_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    string OperacionMontaje = "Montaje";
    string OperacionDesmontaje = "Desmontaje";
    // 2024-03-18: Obtengo de la lista del ViewState, la suma de las ubicaciones de las llantas montadas.
    var q1 = from a in Registros
             where
                 a.OperacionLlanta == OperacionMontaje
             group a by a.OperacionLlanta into GrupoA
             select new CountCargo
             {
                 Cargo = GrupoA.Key,
                 Count = GrupoA.Sum(a => a.UbicacionLlanta)
             };
    var q2 = q1.ToList();
    // 2024-03-18: Obtengo la cantidad de llantas registradas en el ViewState
    double SumaUbicacionMontaje = q2.Count;
}
```

El campo a.UbicacionLlanta, contiene los números 4 y 8 ya que solo son dos registros, lo que implicaría que al sumarlos, debería dar 12, pero esta dando 1. Pareciera que en lugar de sumar estuviera contando los registros, que para este caso, al agrupar, solo sería uno. Pensamos que podría ser que el campo a.UbicacionLlanta era de tipo string y eso impediría que se diera la suma, pero luego de validar, identificamos que es de tipo decimal.

Agradecemos la ayuda que nos puedan brindar.

Comment: yo no soy experto en linq, y nunca me gusta esta forma de linq... pero mas alla de eso, veo toda esa consulta rarisima... si estas igualando OperacionLlanta a un solo valor, entonces no tiene sentido agrupar, porque hay un solo valor... luego, si obtuviste una lista con todas las mismas keys, el sum es mas simple si lo sacas y lo haces despues..

Comment: Hola gbianchi, me podrías indicar como seria la forma de hacerlo, en particular cuando dices que  "si lo sacas y lo sumas despúes". No sabría como hacerlo. Te agradecemos.

Comment: yo no soy su experto en esto.. solo aclare puntos que no estan bien...

Comment: Yo llevo indicándole lo mismo varias veces. Hay algunos motores donde requieres agrupar obligatoriamente para realizar funciones de agregación como `SUM`, no es el caso de Linq. Aquí puedes usar SUM o Count, o cualquier función SIN necesidad de agrupar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Atendiendo a lo que dices en tu publicación me parece que tú solución sería de esta forma:

```
var suma = Registros.Where(r => r.OperacionLlanta == OperacionMontaje).
           Sum(x => x.UbicacionLlanta);
```

Primero aplicas la **función Where** para filtrar por el criterio deseado y posteriormente aplicas la **función Sum** para sumar por el campo deseado.

Comment: Como me gusta alguien que me lee el pensamiento y simplifica las cosas :)

Comment: Gracias @gbianchi, esperemos sea la respuesta correcta ;)

Answer (score 0):

Aprovechando las observaciones de los usuarios gbianchi y Japy, pudimos encontrar otra solución que se ajusta a nuestro estilo de desarrollo, procedo a compartirla:

```
protected void CVSumaUbicaciones_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    string OperacionMontaje = "Montaje";
    string OperacionDesmontaje = "Desmontaje";
    // 2024-03-18: Obtengo de la lista del ViewState, la suma de las ubicaciones de las llantas montadas.

    var q1 = from a in Registros
             where
                 a.OperacionLlanta == OperacionMontaje
             select new CountCargo
             {
                 Cargo = a.OperacionLlanta,
                 Count = a.UbicacionLlanta
             };
    var SumaUbicacionMontaje = q1.Sum(a => a.Count);
}
```

En primer lugar, pudimos entender que si ya estábamos filtrando por el campo OperacionLlanta, ya no era necesario hacer group by. Lo segundo que pudimos entender, fue que dentro del select no debía hacer la suma, sino fuera de este por medio de la expresión lambda q1.Sum(a => a.Count). Con estas dos observaciones y correcciones al código inicial pudimos llegar al resultado deseado.